# Reduce total number of model development for multiple time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I need to generate 24 hour forecast for 600 different time series. All these time series are basically hourly electricity prices for different pricing nodes. I wanted to understand if there is a way through which my number of models to be built for these 600 time series can be reduced? or Is their a method through which a single model or 10-20 models would suffice for all the 600 time series? Any direction in this regard would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a data set that requires hourly effects, daily effects, monthly effects,  holiday effects . particular days-of-the-month and memory effects just to name a few. It might be possible to specify a general model AFTER looking at the a number of representative models and to identify the generic approach. This could then be used as a starting model to shorten the analytics stage.

Comment: Thank you and my apologies for getting back so late.I did not get any notification that my question was answered, I have a follow up question, can you please elaborate on what is meant by memory effects? and How can I add days of the month information to the model?